# Thevenin equivalent- what did my professor do

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

I have to find the Thévenin equivalent of this circuit. The point of interest here is 4.
[image: given circuit]

I reduced it down and got the same resistance value as my professor, but I still had the original 10V as my Thévenin voltage while he has 0.77V. Looking at his solution, whenever I made a move to combine resistors he did something that changed the source voltage too. This doesn't make sense to me because it is a source. It seems like no matter what you do to the resistors, the source voltage should stay the same. First I thought oh, he must be using source transforms. Then I thought maybe he was using the voltage divider equation but I don't think that is correct. I don't think I have seen whatever rule or attribute he is using before.

What is he doing?

His solution:
[image]

Ignore that 3k resistor on the right. It is for another part of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Looking at his solution, whenever I made a move to combine resistors
> he did something that changed the source voltage too. This doesn't
> make sense to me because it is a source.

I can understand your sensibility here, that the voltage supply simply is a voltage supply. So you don't imagine it should change.

Bet let's look at just the easier first part:

[image]

What voltage must you measure at point #2? I think you'd agree that we should measure \$5\:\text{V}\$, right? Half of the source voltage? So let's look the Thevenin equivalent:

[image]

Now, if you were measuring at point #2, you ***should*** still measure \$5\:\text{V}\$ (or else it isn't equivalent.) The only way that happens is if the voltage source is \$5\:\text{V}\$, too. So it must be this:

[image]

Now, I think you already agree that the resistor value here should be \$10\:\text{k}\Omega\$:

[image]

But to prove it, let's think about the idea of adding as \$12\:\text{k}\Omega\$ from point #2 to ground, in parallel with that nearby \$20\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor in the original (before conversion) circuit.

What should the voltage be at point #2 in the case ***before*** converting and ***after***?

***Before*** conversion, you need to first get the parallel resistance of that pair, or \$7.5\:\text{k}\Omega\$. Then work out the voltage as \$10\:\text{V}\cdot\frac{7.5\:\text{k}\Omega}{20\:\text{k}\Omega+7.5\:\text{k}\Omega}=\frac{30}{11}\:\text{V}\approx 2.727\:\text{V}\$.

***After*** conversion, you only need to find the voltage as \$5\:\text{V}\cdot\frac{12\:\text{k}\Omega}{10\:\text{k}\Omega+12\:\text{k}\Omega}=\frac{30}{11}\:\text{V}\approx 2.727\:\text{V}\$.

So it really does seem to be the right equivalent circuit.

If you had kept the \$10\:\text{V}\$ source after conversion you would not get the right voltage either before or after adding a load resistor. But if the voltage source is appropriately changed, as well, then the right voltage appears both before and after loading. Which is good.

At this point you just carry on, as before. But now you will have a Thevenin source resistance that isn't zero, anymore. So as you move forward through the process, you will have to account for that, as well.

Answer (score 0):

The prof used repeatedly the most common Thevenin equivalent in practical analog electronics design. He replaced a voltage source + a voltage divider with its Thevenin equivalent and he did it three times. Just that Thevenin equivalent pops up in practical design work so often that I'm not at all sure would I survive if I couldn't recall it from my memory in a second.

Your Et=10V is nonsense. The original 10V is reduced with three successive voltage dividers to a lower voltage.

Comment: What is this most common Thévenin equivalent? Good to know it shows up often.

Comment: The prof applied it three times. The first usage was done when the 10V source and the voltage divider leftwards from node 2 were replaced by 5V source and 10 kOhm series resistor in your 2nd Image, The 5V is the unloaded output of the voltage divider and the 10 kOhm is the parallel of the resistors of the voltage divider. If you for some reason never learn this you are in trouble.